# Analysis of most common n-grams

Tags: python, nlp

Good day,

I have been studying NLP and came across this code for top n-gram extraction:

```
def get_top_tweet_bigrams(corpus, n=None):
    vec = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2, 2)).fit(corpus)
    bag_of_words = vec.transform(corpus)
    sum_words = bag_of_words.sum(axis=0) 
    words_freq = [(word, sum_words[0, idx]) for word, idx in vec.vocabulary_.items()]
    words_freq =sorted(words_freq, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return words_freq[:n]
```

I have gone over this function line by line and the part i cannot figure out is this one:

[**(word, sum_words[0, idx])** for word, idx in vec.vocabulary_.items()]

I do understand what it achieves, but what I don't understand is how. Why simply extracting idx from vec.vocabulary_.items() gives us incorrect count? And what does the matrix sum_words hold? What are those values? Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `bag_of_words` is the usual 2-dimension document-ngram frequency matrix, i.e. it contains the frequency of any ngram for any document (`corpus` might contain any number of documents).
- `sum_words` obtains the sum of the frequency across documents for every ngram. It's a single dimension array. Length is the vocabulary size, and the indexes are in the same order as in `bag_of_words`. It doesn't contain the ngrams themselves, of course.

Since the goal is to obtain the top frequent ngrams, we need to match every ngram to its frequency in `sum_words`. This is why the vocabulary (which contains the ngrams) is iterated with the ngram and the index: if only the index `idx` was obtained, there would be no way to know which actual ngram it represents. And of course the index is used to obtain the total frequency in `sum_words`. Thus `words_freq` is an array containing pairs (ngram, frequency) for every ngram.

The last 2 lines sort this array by decreasing frequency and extract the top `n` elements.